# How to show whats the difference between this Friday and last Friday by Timelion?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, timelion

Timelion says that can show 'Whats the difference between this Friday and last Friday'. But I can't find any demo for that. Do you have any idea how to show whats the difference between this Friday and last Friday by Timelion?

Answer (score 1):

> All data sources can receive an offset argument, eg offset=-1M to
>   compare last month as if it was happening now

From https://www.elastic.co/blog/timelion-timeline.

Such as `.es(*, offset=-1w),.es(*)`